# How to limit the running time of a program?

Tags: limit

Sometimes when I write code I found that I made a stupid mistake and some loop takes almost all CPU time forever. Is there a way the running time of a program for example to 10 seconds in bash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `timeout` command will do this for you, i.e.

```
timeout 10s command
```

It will kill `command` after 10 seconds. Instead of `s` for seconds, you can also use `m` for minutes, `h` for hours or `d` for days.

Comment: One just has to love the BUGS section of `man timeout`: "Some platforms don't curently support timeouts beyond 2038"